# Spree REST API product images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, spree

Spree REST API does not returns product images URLs when I request products list on `/api/products.json`.

Can I generate image URL or get it somehow else or I need to edit Spree source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skayred,

You will have to extend the Spree source in order to get this information reliably.

It's probably as simple as overriding the object_serialization_options the Api Products Controller. I believe adding the following to an override should work.

```
Spree::Api::ProductsController.class_eval do
   def object_serialization_options
      { :include => [:master, :variants, :taxons, :images] }
   end
end
```

Comment: The new API includes images and image URLS.